# How can I create rows for dates missing from a range?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g, subquery

I am trying to get data for all dates in a range provided by my query, but I'm only getting the dates that actually exist in my table - missing dates are not reported. I need to create records in the table for those missing dates, with other columns left null, and then include them in the results.

My table `table_name` has records like:

```
  ID  Name  Date_only
----  ----  -----------
1234  xyz   01-Jan-2014
1234  xyz   02-Jan-2014
1234  xyz   04-Jan-2014
...
```

For example, for the range 01-Jan-2014 to 04-Jan-2014, my query is:

```
select * from table_name
where id=1234
and (date_only >= '01-Jan-14' and date_only <= '04-Jan-14')
```

From Java or queried directly this shows three rows, with no data for 03-Jan-2014.

I need a single statement to insert rows for any missing dates into the table and return the data for all four rows. How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

Followed query worked for only if only 1 record available in table OR search range 2-5 days,

`SELECT LEVEL, to_date('2014-11-08','yyyy-mm-dd') + level as day_as_date FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10` .

**UPDATE WITH FIDDLE EXAMPLE**

I got Error is:
I have table data and same query executed then i got error is **ORA-02393: exceeded call limit on CPU usage**,  fiddle example is : [my owntable sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c727/2) .thanks in advance

Comment: The query you showed won't match any of your three records - or any record, a field can't be equal to two things at once.. Do you actually want to insert a row in the table for the missing dates in the range - and if so with what values for the other columns? - or just include it in the result set with a blank value?

Comment: thanks @Alex Poole, Sorry, now updated my question,  i need in result set with 4 records and update that record in table also.

Comment: and with single request passing from & to dates then insert missing dates and include in result set that total missing dates records also.

Comment: You can't do an insert (or in this case a merge) and get the query results in one plain SQL statement. You could use two statements - an execute for a merge, and an executeQuery for the select - or wrap both parts into a procedure that has a ref cursor as an out parameter.

Comment: thanks @Alex Poole, please can you share some code for this, its is very help for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the below SQL for your purpose.The sql fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ee61/27

```
with start_and_end_dates as (select min(onlydate) min_date
,max(onlydate) max_date
from mytable
where id='1001'
and onlydate >= to_date('01-Jan-2015','dd-Mon-YYYY') 
and onlydate <= to_date('04-Jan-2015','dd-Mon-YYYY')),

missing_dates as (select min_date + level-1  as date_value 
from start_and_end_dates connect by level <=(max_date - min_date) + 1)

select distinct id,name,date_value
from mytable,missing_dates
where id='1001'
order by date_value
```

**EDIT1:-** Using your other example.The sqlfiddle is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c727/16

```
with start_and_end_dates as (select min(onlydate) min_date
,max(onlydate) max_date
from mytable
where name='ABCD'),

missing_dates as (select min_date + level-1  as date_value 
from start_and_end_dates connect by level <=(max_date - min_date) + 1)

select distinct id,name,date_value
from mytable,missing_dates
where name='ABCD'
order by date_value;
```

Comment: For between From & To Dates Range : `with start_and_end_dates as (select min(to_date(fromDate,'dd-MM-yyyy')) min_date,max(to_date(ToDate,'dd-MM-yyyy')) max_date from mytable
where name='ABCD') ....etc`.

Comment: For the example the fromdate and todate should be in where clause like the first answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like

```
SELECT LEVEL, to_date('2014-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + level as day_as_date
  FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000
```

to get a list of 1000 days from Jan 1 2014 (adjust to your need)

Next do an insert from select

```
INSERT INTO table_name (date_only)
SELECT day_as_date FROM (<<THE_QUERY_ABOVE>>)
WHERE day_as_date NOT IN (SELECT date_only FROM table_name)
```

Comment: thanks @ms32035, its working but if i taken 10 its showing more then 10, and its continues...

Comment: Strange. The row selection is ok. Have a look at [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40061)

Comment: thanks @ms32035, still get more records. my command is **SELECT LEVEL, to_date('2014-11-08','yyyy-mm-dd') + level as day_as_date FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10** and my table have data is `1001, abcd,08-11-2014 & 1001,abcd,11-11-2014 & 1001, abcd,13-11-2014 & 1001,abcd,14-11-2014` , these above 4 records available in table, i get results 79 records,in result records have only 10-11-2014 date 8 records and 09-11-2014 dates remain 71 records.

Comment: thanks @ms32035, please look at [sqlfiddle.com example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ee61/4)

Comment: Please have a look what is i got exact facing problem  in this example : [SQLFIDDLE.COM](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c727/2)

Comment: You should be selecting rows from dual not from mytable! I corrected the second fiddle

Comment: thanks @ms32035 : table name  whatever, i have table data and same query executed thne i got error is **ORA-02393: exceeded call limit on CPU usage**,  fiddle example is : [my own table sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c727/2)

Comment: DUAL is not a regular table. It's a special type of Oracle object